# Messy SQL Query Needs to be more Efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, query-optimization

THIS Data pull needs help.  The efficiency/performance sucks and I don't know enough about SQL to make it better.  I'm in the middle of a project that required me to learn SQL pretty fast, but considering the time frame I'm looking at, I've come to YOU, the PROS.... Any ideas from the pros to make this for efficient?

```
SELECT
d.[Date] AS [Date],
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,d.[Date],112),6) AS [YearMo],
FORMAT(d.[Date],'MMMM') AS [Month],
YEAR(d.[Date]) AS [Year],
e.[MbrNo] AS [Member ID],
e.[Mkt_State] AS [Mkt State],
e.[Mkt] AS [Mkt Segment],

COALESCE(e.[Individual_Premium_Amt],0) AS [Individual Premium],
COALESCE(e.[Total_Premium_Amt],0) AS [Total Premium],

COALESCE(v.[Inpatient_Pd],0) AS [Inpatient Pd],
COALESCE(v.[Outpatient_Pd],0) AS [Outpatient Pd],
COALESCE(v.[Professional_Pd],0) AS [Professional Pd],
COALESCE(v.[Other_Pd],0) AS [Other Pd],
COALESCE(v.[Med_Pd],0) AS [Med Pd],
COALESCE(SUM(v.[Med_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date])),0) AS [Total Med Pd YTD],
COALESCE(v.[Med_Allowed],0) AS [Med Allowed],
COALESCE(v.[Rx_Pd],0) AS [Rx Pd],
COALESCE(SUM(v.[Rx_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date])),0) AS [Total RX Pd YTD],
COALESCE(v.[Rx_Allowed],0) AS [Rx Allowed],
COALESCE(v.[Med_RX_Pd],0) AS [Med Rx Pd],
COALESCE(SUM(v.[Med_Pd] + v.[Rx_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date])
    ORDER BY e.[MbrNo],LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,d.[Date],112),6) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),0) AS [RS Med Rx Pd],
COALESCE(SUM(v.[Med_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date]))
    + SUM(v.[Rx_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date])),0) AS [Total Pd YTD],
COALESCE(v.[Med_RX_Allowed],0) AS [Med Rx Allowed],

CASE
    WHEN ((SUM(v.[Med_Pd] + v.[Rx_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date]))) > rr.[Recover_Threshold])
    THEN ((SUM(v.[Med_Pd] + v.[Rx_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date])) - rr.[Recover_Threshold]))
    ELSE 0 
END AS [Recoverable Amt],

SUM(1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date])) AS [MM (Yearly)],

CASE
    WHEN ((SUM(v.[Med_Pd] + v.[Rx_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date]))) > rr.[Recover_Threshold])
    THEN ((SUM(v.[Med_Pd] + v.[Rx_Pd]) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date])) - rr.[Recover_Threshold]))
    / SUM(1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY e.[MbrNo],YEAR(d.[Date]))
    ELSE 0 
END AS [Recoverable Amtv2], 


COALESCE(rr.[Members],0) AS [Members],
COALESCE(rr.[MM],0) AS [MM],
COALESCE(rr.[Rx_Rebates],0) AS [Rx Rebates],
COALESCE(rr.[RA_PMPM],0) AS [RA PMPM],
COALESCE(rr.[RA_Payable],0) AS [RA Payable],
COALESCE(rr.[Pd_Threshold],0) AS [SR Pd Threshold],
COALESCE(rr.[Recover_Threshold],0) AS [SR Recover Threshold],
COALESCE(rr.[CF_Inpatient_PMPM],0) AS [CF IP PMPM],
COALESCE(rr.[CF_Outpatient_PMPM],0) AS [CF OP PMPM],
COALESCE(rr.[CF_Professional_PMPM],0) AS [CF PROF PMPM],
COALESCE(rr.[CF_RX_PMPM],0) AS [CF RX PMPM],
COALESCE(rr.[CF_Med_PMPM],0) AS [CF Med PMPM],
COALESCE(SUM(rr.[CF_RX_PMPM])+(rr.[CF_Med_PMPM]),0) AS [CF Med_Rx PMPM]
```

---

---

```
FROM -- Date Scaffold - Each month starting 20170101 to the current GETDATE() month 
    (SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH,number,'20190101') AS [Date],
        EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,number,'20190101')) AS [EOM Date]
        FROM MASTER..[spt_values]
        WHERE TYPE='P'
            AND DATEADD(MONTH,number,'20190101') <= GETDATE()
    ) AS d
```

---

---

```
INNER JOIN -- Join Med enrollment for each month to the date scaffold, creating the membermonths format
    (SELECT 
        e.*
        FROM [SomeDB].[dbo].[sometable] AS e
        WHERE [benefitType]=930700000
            AND e.[LOB]='Commercial'
            AND e.[Segment_Cancelled]<>'Yes'
            AND e.[Mbr_Status]<>'Pending Binder Payment'
            AND e.[MbrNo]<>0
    ) AS e
        ON e.[Start_Date]<=d.[Date] AND e.[End_Date]>=d.[EOM Date]
```

---

---

```
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        c.[YEARMO],
        c.[MEMBERID],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[UTILGRP]='INPATIENT' THEN c.[Pd] ELSE 0 END) AS [Inpatient_Pd],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[UTILGRP]='OUTPATIENT' THEN c.[Pd] ELSE 0 END) AS [Outpatient_Pd],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[UTILGRP]='PROFESSIONAL' THEN c.[Pd] ELSE 0 END) AS [Professional_Pd],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [UTILGRP]='OTHER' THEN c.[Pd] ELSE 0 END) AS [Other_Pd],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Med' THEN c.[Pd] ELSE 0 END) AS [Med_Pd],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Med' THEN c.[ALLOWED] ELSE 0 END) AS [Med_Allowed],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Pharmacy' THEN c.[Pd] ELSE 0 END) AS [Rx_Pd],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Pharmacy' THEN c.[ALLOWED] ELSE 0 END) AS [Rx_ALlowed],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Med' OR c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Pharmacy' THEN c.[Pd] ELSE 0 END) AS [Med_RX_Pd],
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Med' OR c.[CLAIMTYPE]='Pharmacy' THEN c.[ALLOWED] ELSE 0 END) AS [Med_RX_Allowed]

        FROM [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] AS c

        WHERE c.[MbrNo] <> 0
            AND c.[CLAIMLINESTATUS] NOT IN ('D','V')
            AND c.[LOB]='IND'

        GROUP BY c.[YearMo],c.[MbrNo]

    ) AS v
        ON e.[MbrNo]=v.[MbrNo] AND LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,d.[Date],112),6)=v.[YearMo]
```

---

---

```
LEFT JOIN [SomeDB].[dbo].[SomeTable] AS rr
    ON e.[Mkt_Segment]=rr.[Mkt_Segment] AND LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,d.[Date],112),6)=rr.[YearMo]
```

---

---

```
GROUP BY d.[Date],e.[MbrNo],e.[Mkt_State],e.[Mkt_Segment],e.[Individual_Premium_Amt],e.[Total_Premium_Amt],
v.[Inpatient_Pd],v.[Outpatient_Pd],v.[Professional_Pd],v.[Other_Pd],v.[Med_Pd],v.[Med_Allowed],v.[Rx_Pd],v.[Rx_Allowed],v.[Med_RX_Pd],v.[Med_RX_Allowed],
rr.[Members],rr.[MM],rr.[Rx_Rebates],rr.[RA_PMPM],rr.[RA_Payable],rr.[Pd_Threshold],rr.[Recover_Threshold],rr.[CF_Inpatient_PMPM],rr.[CF_Outpatient_PMPM],rr.[CF_Professional_PMPM],rr.[CF_RX_PMPM],rr.[CF_Med_PMPM]
```

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com for a good introduction to why they're important.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)

Comment: Instead of `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,d.[Date],112),6)=v.[YearMo]` you should select `YEAR(d.Date)` directly in your date "scaffold". And that should also have a `TOP(calculate number of months)`. Check your selected columns and joined tables, if there is no business need for them, remove them

Answer (score 0):

I would replace all the <> 0 statements (Which is typically not SARGable) with >0 statements which is Sargable.